# Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks

Tags: azure, ethereum, solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

When migrating my smart contract to a private Azure block chain I get this.

```
Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks.
```

I am trying to migrate a ScoreStore smart contract which is deployed successfully on the development blockchain provided by truffle develop but the above error comes up after 10 or so minutes when trying to deploy to a private blockchain built using Azure template for Ethereum consortium leader template with defaults(1 transaction node, 2 mining nodes and default genesis block)

I have tried default gas and gasPrice values, even high and low values but this error does not go away.

Anyone has encountered or solved this? how?

Comment: Was the transaction eventually mined? This error (which should probably just be a warning) comes from the client as it attempts to poll for successful mining of pending transactions. It can be misleading because the "error" will happen if the network is heavily congested, your gas price is too low (and therefore not yet picked up), or if your client is connected to a node that is not fully synced.